# How to insert Meta tags in opencart website with scripting?

Tags: php, scripting, opencart, keyword, meta

i have an opencart 1.5 website and i want to add meta keyword in my home page.
Unfortunately there is not any option in the cms to do that.
How can i insert meta tag with using cpanel files with scripting or coding in php?

Comment: https://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=125314

Comment: I've seen this topic, but in this way meta keyword will import to all pages.I want to add just in home page.